# How cloud virtual machines are connected

Tags: google-compute-engine, hpc

I use elasticluster to setup a cluster of GCE virtual machines. My question is related to hardware: When I order a cluster of virtual machines, I would like to know if virtual machines of GCE are connected via cable or wireless?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machines are connected with a virtual layer 3 network. This is implemented as a software defined network on top of a (cabled) datacenter switching fabric. [You can only use IPv4 unicast because of this](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications).